# mmap multiple file chunks and cache mmap objects (Python)

Tags: python, mmap

I don't know what knowledge I've missed for understanding mmap. I just can't figure it out. But let me ask my question this way:

- I have a number of, say, 3 file chunks, of which the sizes are s1, s2, s3.
- s1,s2 and s3 are all smaller than the Size Limit for Mmap (SLM), i.e. s1 < SLM; s2 < SLM; s3 < SLM.
- But s1, s2 and s3 total to be larger than the size limit for mmap, i.e. s1 + s2 + s3 > SLM.
- I'm thinking about mapping the 3 file chunks and caching the mmap objects in a Python dictionary, one mmap object for a file chunk.

My questions are:

- Can the total of file chunk sizes (s1+s2+s3) exceed the size limit for mmap?
- In this case, how does mmap allocate or use the memory and virtual memory?

Any answer would be apprieciated.

Comment: Can you tell where the "Size Limit for Mmap" comes from?  E.g. which man page on which system, or Windows documentation page, etc.

Comment: I really can't tell that. "Size Limit for Mmap" is my own wording. Except that there is some kind of limit, I don't have much understanding about mmap. I'm using Win32, the "size limit for mmap" on my computer is around 1 GB when a single file is mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure just which limit you're talking about, and that may well be system dependent. In Linux, the limit on how much can be mapped depends on RLIMIT_AS and kernel configuration. Depending on memory layout, it is common that you can mmap more than you can malloc (heap allocation, where most Python objects reside).

The per-mmap limits could be system dependent or simply depend on what contiguous ranges are still available in your virtual memory. A look at `/proc/$$/maps` in Linux, or a debugging tool such as MHS on Windows, will inform you how that looks. The primary limitation is that the offset passed to mmap must be a multiple of `mmap.ALLOCATIONGRANULARITY`. Since each mmap must find a gap to fit into within the virtual memory map, multiple mmaps often can exceed the total size of a single possible mmap. Some additional constraints may be in place, such as auto-allocated addresses only being in a certain range, and ranges being restricted to kernel use.

It would also not be surprising to find a limit on the number of mappings at any time; if you're doing many mappings you might have to close ones you're not needing.

Gustavo Duarte posted a fairly good article named [Anatomy of a Program in Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory) which shows what the virtual memory typically contains, and some examples of different OS configurations. The proportions are dependent on system configuration (see for instance the /3GB switch), and 64-bit systems can have much more space.